# Drag & Drop - ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am developing a simple flash game - a drag and drop game for children.

I have created three animal instances which will be dragged and dropped to the correct space. I am just adding action script and am getting the following error when trying to add drag and drop functions;

Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 10, Column 44   1119: Access of possibly undefined property startDragging through a reference with static type String.Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 10, Column 44 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 2.

My code is as follows;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

```
stop();

//set up the buttons for the puzzle pieces

Pig.buttonMode=true;

Pig.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN.startDragging);
Pig.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP.stopDragging);

function startDragging(e:MouseEvent){


trace("startDragging");
```

}

```
function stopDragging(e:MouseEvent){

trace("stopDragging");
```

}

Comment: Dot instead of comma after MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP. Must be Pig.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
Pig.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
Pig.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
```

`MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` is a `String` and it doesn't have a property called `startDragging`. To add a listener you should pass a function reference as a second argument of `addEventListener` (using comma, no a dot)

Comment: Ideally, the MOUSE_UP listener should be added to ```stage``` instead of the object itself (in case the use releases the mouse while the MovieClip/Sprite is still lagging a wee bit behind)

Comment: This mouse up listener being added to the stage is what has given you your next headache. Until you do as Organis suggested an make an Animal class with unique properties, keep the mouse up attached to the Pig and Cow etc, not the stage.